# Auto rank based on which rows has the highest percentage for multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

for example, I have this table:

| rank | company | shares |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alpha | 35.0% |
| 3 | Beta | 25.0% |
| 1 | Charlie | 40.0% |

Trying to achieve this by ranking it based on the shares where the row will become:

| rank | company | shares |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Charlie | 40.0% |
| 2 | Alpha | 35.0% |
| 3 | Beta | 25.0% |

I try using this - RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$4), but the rank is still not ascending/descending.

Comment: Just sort by rank???

Comment: hi @findwindow, I did try rank function but did not achieve the 2nd table

Comment: You can just sort the table by rank column.

Comment: If you already have a Rank column (your column A), then why would you need a Rank Function? Is Column A a formula, or rather, just a number?